ServiceNow Cloud Runner not running tests as per the execution order
When I run ServiceNow ATF scripts using Cloud Runner by assigning them order number e.g. 1-20, the tests are not run in order defined, it runs test #11 after test #1, it should run in order like 1,2,3,4.....
if anyone can help me here, I am new to CloudRunner.
